# "Show in documentation" feature in Pydev?

Tags: pydev

Does Pydev have a "Show in Documentation" feature that can show the Python documentation of a code item in e.g. a web browser? If it does not have a feature like this by default, is there a way to install it?

Comment: Good question ... hoping for an answer too. I'd suggest changing the title though, to something like '"Show in documentation" feature in PyDev'. now it is a bit unclear what the title means.

Comment: @Samuel Lampa -thank you, updated the question's title.